# How to connect an external inventory management program with magento

Tags: magento, inventory

Is there any possibility for connecting an external inventory management program with magento? Our customer wants to keep magento's stock synchronized with the "real" stock of his products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to look into the [Magento DataFlow](http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/screencasts/data-exporting/view) System (it even has its own [support forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewforum/85/)).  Someone may already have implemented a commercial and/or free implementation for you specific Inventory Management Program, or you may have to develop feeds from nothing. Google around and see what you find. Either way you're looking at a "medium" development effort for you or the guy you hire.

It's also worth contacting the vendor of the Inventory Management System to see if they have a standard way of dealing with Magento.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check out DataFlow :-)